# Accessing Android service in onCreate after declaration

Tags: android

When I run the following code, the service value is null. However, if I call it from something outside of the onCreate (like a button) it works.

How can I access this from the onCreate method without user input.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(ISoundControlService.class.getName()),
         serConnSound, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    try {
        soundService.start();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
getting the service...

```
private ServiceConnection serConnSound = new ServiceConnection() {
     @Override
     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
         soundService = ISoundControlService.Stub.asInterface(service);
     }

     @Override
     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        soundService = null;
     }
};
```

Comment: Hmm.. How do you initialuze soundService variable?

Comment: See Update For More Info

Answer (score 1):

I would say: *you can't*

That's the whole point of `ServiceConnection`. It's initialized asynchronously and you have to deal with that fact. When `onServiceConnected` is called your service will be available. As long as you are waiting for that callback your service variable will be `null`...

Comment: So would the correct way to handle this be to use a Broadcast Reciever that calls the method and broadcast from the onServiceonnected

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `bindService` requests the service and `onServiceConnected` will be called as soon the service is started and is ready to use. Until then you just can't use the service. Check service for `null` or display a progress dialog as long `onServiceConnected` is not called...